# how to make google maps multiple markers from database in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-maps

I need how to make google multiple markers form database in php, i have created DB and i inserted latitude and longitude location value,so i need pass database  latitude and longitude value and show google map multiple markers.
already i have done this but i'm saving all the value in xml files but i don't want like this i need pass form database please help any one.

Here my code HTML and javascript code:

```
<div class="map">
      <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
            var customLabel = {
        restaurant: {
          label: 'R'
        },
        bar: {
          label: 'B'
        }
      };
        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.92279500, 77.61440500),
          zoom: 12
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
            downloadUrl('http://localhost/rentozy/rentozy.xml', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('pg_id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('pg_address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('pg_type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }
      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
 key=your_api_key&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    </div>
```

Here my php code:

```
$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'root'; 
$dbpwd  =   ''; 
$dbname =   'rentozy_db';
$db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
$sql='select * from `tbl_master_property`;';
    $result=$db->query( $sql );
    $attribs=array('pg_id','name','pg_address','lat','lng','pg_type');
    $dom=new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $root=$dom->createElement('tbl_master_property');
    $dom->appendChild($root);
    while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() ){
        $node=$dom->createElement('tbl_master_property');
        $root->appendChild($node);

         foreach( $attribs as $attrib ){
            $attr = $dom->createAttribute($attrib);
            $value= $dom->createTextNode($rs->$attrib);
            $attr->appendChild($value);
            $node->appendChild($attr);
        }
      }
    echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add php for looping you query into your javascript code, like

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

var mapOptions = {
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('your_id'), mapOptions);

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


<?php
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from tbl_master_property");
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $name = $data['name'];
        $lat = $data['lat'];
        $lon = $data['lon'];

        echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>$name</b>');\n");                        
    }
?>

function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: location
    });       
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, info);
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```